# Debug gwt inside facebook iframe

Tags: facebook, gwt, iframe

I'm trying to debug my gwt 2.0 apllication that runs inside facebook iframe.

When i use 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997' as "Canvas Callback URL" my app doesn't loading, but when i compile it and use 'http://127.0.0.1:8888' it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

There is a cross site scripting issue with using the GWT debugger within the facebook iframe.
I logged this as issue #4468 
 http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4468

Within that ticket, I specified the workaround is to edit the hosted.html file thusly:

```
hosted.html
gwtOnLoad = function(errFn, modName, modBase){
....
  var topWin = window.top;
  var url = topWin.location.href;
...

Workaround if you have one:

  var topWin = window;
  var url = topWin.location.href;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue for deployment mode. Basically I want my GWT to be managed from a single entry point deployment and be able to run it as widget on 3'rd party websites, without them have to download my application into their host, only using the selector script as reference to my GWT app.

There is a problem doing that due to SOP limitation of current bootstrap process that uses an "iframe" to load the compiled script asynchronously.

I created a workaround procedure for that, let GWT app be installed using 'script' instead of 'iframe'. This makes my GWT available for 3'rd party websites, and let me maintain a single entry point of deployment.

The following article describe my workaround procedure:

[Make GWT Widget Avialble For 3'rd party websites](http://www.rhizomenetworks.com/Make-GWT-Widget-Avialble-For-3rd-Party-Websites)

Comment: This appears to be an unrelated issue.

Answer (score -3):

127.0.0.1 is a reserved IP address that always resolves to localhost.  So when you enter that as a Facebook canvas URL, Facebook tries to access it's own servers.  A request never comes to your computer, which is where the application is actually hosted.  Of course, when *you* access it at 127.0.0.1, it works fine, because your localhost is your own machine.

You need to figure out your external IP address, and enter that as the Canvas Callback URL.  You can check your router settings, or go to something like http://www.whatismyip.com/.  Once you have it, try accessing your application using it directly instead of 127.0.0.1.  You might have to change your router or firewall to allow port 8888 through.  Once you have it working, enter it as your Canvas Callback URL in your Facebook application settings.

Comment: I have used http://127.0.0.1:8888 as Canvas Callback URL and it works so i thing there's something with gwt debug server. Also i've used firebug to check what requests are called from facebook and i  get:
GET request to 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 (with some other facebook parameters) which returned my application index.html. But gwt doesn't load.

When I pasted above url directly to browser my app started succefully,and firebug show that there was one more request to
http://127.0.0.1:8888/myapp/hosted.html?myapp

Comment: also this help to set P3P headers

http://www.tomred.net/java-tomcat-set-expires-headers.html

just substitute

    ((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader("P3P","CP=HONK"); //P3P: CP=HONK

Comment: This answer is wrong: The Javascript is executed on the client, not on the server - and the `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` thus refers to the client's own host, not to the server.