# Problems with adding a GWT app in an iFrame

Tags: java, gwt, iframe, gwt2, gwt-2.3

I have a `GWT` application, and I want to embed its **URL** in another web page through an `iFrame`:

```
<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/myProject.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997"/>
```

But I'm getting errors.

If I browsed it in **[firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)**:

`Permission denied to access property 'href'` (from firebug console)

If I browsed it in **[chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome)**:

A dialog pops up saying: `Plugin failed to connect to Development Mode server at 127.0.0.1:9997`

I researched a lot but all were in vain.

Using development mode of *GWT*.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1st the obvious thing jumping out at me.  That's the (I'm assuming eclipse) testing url.  Do you have the internal server running?

Comment: @IanJacobs yeah, I am running it through the development mode, eclipse is providing me the URL, and I'm copy/pasting it in an html file inside an iframe tag.

Comment: is http://127.0.0.1:8888/myProject.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 (as a regular html page) work? can you compile it and try if it's work in release mode? also- try to move the gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 to the outer (main) page. so the gwt plugin read it

Comment: @shem Yeah GWT works as a regular html page. Yes GWT works in release mode.    
What do you mean by `try to move the gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 to the outer (main) page`

Comment: if you main page that contain the GWT iframe called main.html, try to run it like this: main.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

Comment: @shem the same result :(

Comment: is the main page is public html or a in-house hosted? anyway- try put your ip instead 127.0.0.1

Comment: @shem Looks like the `host` and the `port` of the main page and `GWT` must be the same, or it will do errors...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11319/discussion-between-shem-and-mike-myers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK if someone ever get here cause 
[he has the same problem and want to know what happened](http://xkcd.com/979/) 
I will just summarize what we've got.

I'm not sure but I think that the problem was because internet browsers don't let sites to access `url` that are not in the main page domain (if it was able to do so very bad things would have happened) unless you let them do so.

It's called cross-domain access policy, so there are 2 options for handling it

1. The easy one- the gwt and the outer html must have the same host.
2. Let gwt plugin run from the outer html context, it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646544/debug-gwt-inside-facebook-iframe/3283940#3283940) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4468) but for some reason it wasn't working. we still don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround (Ubuntu, GWT 2.5.1) was to replace:

```
__gwt_HostedModePlugin -> parent.__gwt_HostedModePlugin
window.top -> window.parent
```

in hosted.html